# Ubuntu 14.04 - Strange problem - browsing makes screen go black!

Tags: 14.04

I have installed the Ubuntu 14.04 version. Following is the problem I face:
1. Open Mozilla Browser
2. Try to access gmail.com or google.com/chrome
3. Browser tries to load
Kabam - The screen goes black! The system is still on but there's no way I can see anything.
I am completely clueless as to what is the issue. No screensaver on or active neither any timed screen blank issue.
Any clues?

Comment: Are you using an Intel video graphics adapter? Type lspci in a terminal and check the video controller line.

Comment: Yes I get Intel as Display adapter..

Comment: @Stormlord what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the xorg edgers ppa to your system and update it like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After the new intel video drivers have been installed, reboot your system.

This should fix the problem, leaving a small remaining bug that can be fixed by installing kernel 3.19.  In a few days it will be released for 14.04 by Canonical officially and you will be able to install it.  Alternatively, you can install the mainline kernel but this is not recommended since it's not 100% sure the rest of the system will function ok after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked.. what was the source of issue? the drivers right?

Comment: Yes, intel drivers and mesa.  ;)

Comment: Kernel 3.19 is now officially available for 14.04 in the repos.  The package name is linux-generic-lts-vivid.  You can install it to complete the fix.